# PDO statement error php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i am trying to fetch product list from mysql table. I am trying the following code but it is not working. Any suggestions please.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::rowCount()

**Code**

```
$query = "SELECT id, name, price FROM female_products ORDER BY name";
$stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute();
$num = $stmt->rowCount();
if($num>0)
{
//my work here
}
```

**Config.php**

```
 $db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_name = 'ecommerce';
$db_host = 'localhost';

try {
$con  = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name);

 }catch(PDOException $exception){
echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
 }
```

Comment: use try/catch so yo get your error message!

Comment: i have edited the question with the error

Comment: He means the PDO SQL Statement, not the PHP Statement.

Comment: how do we reconcile PDO in title with mysqli error message ? Choose one interface, not both

Comment: If PDO then why is mysqli in the error message?

Comment: Show more code, because it is unclear how you try to accomplish your task. How did you start db connection $con??

Comment: @Terradon i have edited my question

Comment: Do you understand difference between `PDO` and `mysqli`?

Comment: cool thing is that you are just starting out. imo stick with PDO

Comment: @u_mulder oops! my mistake :) thanks i have corrected it

Comment: If you want to use PDO functions, you have to use a PDO connection: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a real PDO solution, rather then a mysqli one:

```
    try {
    $aOptions = array(  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // play around with options

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.DBHOST.';dbname='.DBNAME.';charset=utf8', ''.DBUSER.'', ''.DBPWD.'',$aOptions); 
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
    // do something smarter then just echo error!
}


$sql = "SELECT id, name, price FROM female_products ORDER BY name";
$stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
$aArray = $stmt->fetchAll();

if(count($aArray) > 0){
    // do something
}
else{
   // empty result 
}
```

I personally think PDO is a much easier style then mysqli.
Options: you certainly gonna play with it soon, so it is handy to use an array for it.
You have used prepare,but yo do not make use of a prepared statement yet??
If this code works, try to find out hoe prepared statements work: one of the best defenses against SQL attacks!!

For configuration i used constants, so you need to define theme in your config. Constants, because they will never change during execution of your script!

Comment: ok, now forget mysqli and stick to PDO and your life will become much easier. Just read more about PDO especially the prepared statements

Comment: sure i will !! thanks :)